# How to calculate the Vref and X_CURRENT for a TMC2130 stepper driver, knowing the rated current of the stepper motor?

Tags: marlin, stepper, stepper-driver, tmc2130

I have written [a question about this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13304/i-can-set-the-voltage-and-current-of-the-tmc2130-driver-manually-but-in-which) but I found new information in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUadiW5QLBE) and I want to go more to the point.

My motor "rated current" is 1.4V. I assume that this is the maximum current

[image: motor_current]

The guy explains in the video how to calculate the Vref and the X_CURRENT value of Marlin

```
RMS current = Max current / 1.41 = 1.3 / 1.41 = 0.92
Vref = (RMS Current x 2.5) / 1.77 = 1.3 V
90% Vref = 1.17 V       // to avoid maximum power in the motor
X_CURRENT = 1170 mA     // magic, I don't know why the guy of Teaching Tech does this convertion
```

Actually, I have read just now that one person says in a comment of the video:

> [...] the numbers are wrong. When populating the current values in Marlin, it's asking for the RMS value in mA, not VREF. If we take the given values and take 90% of what's calculated, we'd end up with [...]

So the new calculation would be:

```
X_CURRENT = 90% RMS current = 0.92 * 0.90 = 0.828 A = 828 mA
```

I have also read in the TMC2130 datasheet:

> Integrated power MOSFETs handle motor currents up to 1.2A RMS (QFN package) / 1.4A RMS (TQFP) or 2.5A short time peak current per coil.

### Questions

- Is he right? Why is he converting `1.17 V => 1170 mA` directly?
- The rated current shown in the motor datasheet is the same as the maximum current?
- As `1.170 A < 1.2 A RMS` or `0.828 A < 1.2 A RMS`, the driver will not shut off, right?
- Are my calculations right?